# Matlab issues with large image files

Tags: matlab, image-processing, out-of-memory, large-files

I am currently facing a new batch of hyperspectral images in Matlab. Usually, I have no problems, but this time images of around 2000x2000x324 (double) have flooded me with "Out of memory" messages for all the image processing and statistical analyses I was a happily doing before.

My pc is relatively good ( Intel Core i7 and a total of available RAM of 15.8 GB but says available 7), so I am surprised.

I was wondering if you have any suggestions, strategy for dealing with such files or I am missing something here.

I have been suggested to switch to python for larger files, but with Matlab I have been having an intimate relationship for a while now.

Thank you very much for your support.

E

Comment: That's about 10 GB of memory total. You probably want to work out a way to process the data in chunks. Any specific method would be dependent on the format of the data and the statistics you are trying to compute. You may also be interested in [memory mapping](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/memory-mapping.html).

Comment: Its a RAM problem, python wont give you magically more RAM, so no need to cchange. You just need to process the data in pieces

Comment: What are the sizes of images you were processing earlier? If half this size you could process, I would suggest using single-precision floats instead of doubles. Otherwise, block-wise processing (chunks, pieces, as suggested) would be the only way to go.

Comment: Check if the "MATLAB array size limit" is set to 100% of RAM or not. This option is present in the Workspace preferences of MATLAB. Try disabling this limit if you still get Out of memory errors

Comment: Thanks everyone, all the comments being useful.I am working on the memory mapping and processing the data in chunks, or filtering information prior to procesing.